# How do I check if object property is true/false and output based on true/false

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to figure this one out - if someone has some pointers I would appriciate it. Basically I got an object which has 3 properties, I need to check if one of those properties is true or false, and return based true/false.
So far, made this code but as I understand it doesn't recognize object.properties..

```js
const library = [
  {
    title: "Bill Gates",
    author: "The Road Ahead",
    isRead: true
  },
  {
    title: "Steve Jobs",
    author: "Walter Isaacson",
    isRead: true
  },
  {
    title: "Mockingjay: The Final Book of The Hunger Games",
    author: "Suzanne Collins",
    isRead: false
  }
];

const showStatus = (arg) => {
  let book = arg;
  for(let i = 0;i < book.length; i++){
    if(book.isRead === true){
       console.log(`Already read ${book.title} by ${book.author}.`)
    } else {
      console.log(`You still need to read ${book.title} by ${book.author}`)
    }

  }

};

showStatus(library);
```

Comment: Use `book[i].isRead` and `book[i].title` and `book[i].author`. You need to access the `i` th index from the book array to access those inner objects and from that object, you need to access the property. There is no `isRead` property in the `book` array

Comment: `arg = libary`, `book = arg`, hence `book = library`. You're confusing yourself with your own naming. `book` is the array of books, not a single book. You need to use `i` somewhere to access a single book in the array of books…

Comment: Your `book` variable is actually your entire library. When you check the title `book.isRead`, it actually checks for `library.isRead`. If you want to check for an individuel book, you need to use your `i` index: `book[i].isRead`. Also you should rename `book` to `books`.

Comment: You can also use native methods like array.forEach

Answer (score 5):

You take not really a book, like

```
const book = arg[i], // iterate arg
```

You could iterate the books and destructure a single entry into the parts and use this parts.

```js
const library = [{
    title: "Bill Gates",
    author: "The Road Ahead",
    isRead: true
  },
  {
    title: "Steve Jobs",
    author: "Walter Isaacson",
    isRead: true
  },
  {
    title: "Mockingjay: The Final Book of The Hunger Games",
    author: "Suzanne Collins",
    isRead: false
  }
];

const showStatus = (books) => {
    for (const { title, author, isRead } of books) {
        if (isRead) {
            console.log(`Already read ${title} by ${author}.`);
        } else {
            console.log(`You still need to read ${title} by ${author}`);
        }
    }
};

showStatus(library);
```